# After I add vuex persist plugin I cannot get store in router

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

After I add vuex persist plugin I cannot get store in router.

```
const vuexPersist = new VuexPersist({
    key: "vuex",
    storage: localStorage
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    modules: {
        alertStorage,
        userStorage,
    },
    //plugins: [vuexPersist.plugin] <-- if I comment out this, its working
});
```

In the router:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    console.log(userStorage.state._user);
    next();
}
```

The result when the line is commented out:

[image: when working]

And when it's not:

[image: not working]

Plus info, this is how my store looks like:

```
import {Module, Mutation, VuexModule} from "vuex-module-decorators";
import {UserResponseDto} from "@/common/dto/user-response-dto";
import Utils from "@/common/utils";

@Module
export default class UserStorage extends VuexModule{
     _user: UserResponseDto = {} as UserResponseDto;

    @Mutation
    protected loginUser(user: UserResponseDto) {
        this._user = user;
    }

    @Mutation
    protected logoutUser() {
        this._user = {} as UserResponseDto;
    }

    get isLoggedIn() {
        return !Utils.isEmpty(this._user);
    }

    get user():UserResponseDto{
        return this._user;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a normal behavior because you must instruct it to use the `localStorage` of the current browser `window`.

There are 2 ways to achieve this:

```
const vuexPersist = new VuexPersist({
    key: "vuex",
    storage: window.localStorage // modified here
});
```

Or do not precise the storage at all:

```
const vuexPersist = new VuexPersist({
    key: "vuex"
});
```

In this later situation, the default storage is: `window.localStorage`.

In both situations, you must inject the plugin to Vuex:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    modules: {
        alertStorage,
        userStorage,
    },
    plugins: [vuexPersist.plugin] // Do not comment it out
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not working. I have tried both that you mentioned.

Comment: Yes I am using `Vue.js` with `Typescript`. I also added plus info for my question.

Comment: Ok,the `vuex-persist` its seems to working in vue.ja files `.vue` but not in my router which is a .ts file. Any idea?

Comment: I found a workaorund but it would better without this. 


`let val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('vuex') as string);
  let userResponse = val.userStorage._user as UserResponseDto;`